# How to print out specific lines of user input to console (C++)

Tags: c++, terminal, console

I am using c++ and the terminal. So my program takes in user input using `read(STD_FILENO,buf,BUFFER` and I am trying to write back only specific lines.

So for example, if the user entered in a total of 10 lines, how would I print out lines 3 through 7 or 6 through 10?

I am trying to use the `write()` function (`write(STD_FILENO,buf,BUFFER)`) but it's not printing what I want it to.
I have tried messing around with the BUFFER and tried to make it smaller than the total amount of characters that the user has input, but it is still not working.

My understanding is that whatever I say the `BUFFER` is to be, it will write UP TO that BUFFER value, so it will start from 0 to BUFFER. But if I wanted to start from line 6, that may start on character #15 and not 0...does this make sense?

please note: I need to use `read()` and `write()`

Thank You!

Comment: If you are dealing with lines of input, why don't you use `std::getline()` instead of `read()`??

Comment: Then at least use [`gets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/gets)?

Comment: Well, [clarify](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47118870/edit) all that in your question, and provide a [MCVE] of what you have so far, including a detailed description which particular problems you met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are required to only use [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) and [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html), then you'll also need [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), [close(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html), [lseek(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) and you need to design and code your own buffered IO library above it. Read carefully the documentation of every system call mentioned here. Use the result of each of them. Handle error cases in your code. See [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) & [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html).

So *keep a buffer* (or more than one) and *several pointers* (or offsets) into it (probably at least the currently consumed position, and the last `read` position, etc).

Perhaps you'll want to use some [container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). You might start implementing your own equivalent of `fgetc` on your buffered IO class, and build above that.

Lines do not really exist at the system call level. You need to take care of `\n` in your code.

BTW you could study, for inspiration, the source code of several [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) C libraries implementing `<stdio.h>`, such as [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/)

Of course you should compile with all warnings and debug info ( `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and you'll need to use the debugger `gdb` to understand the behavior of your program and find your bugs. Don't be shy in drawing on some board what happens in your [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) (with pointers represented by arrows).

NB: SO is not a *do-my-homework* service.

Comment: /OT So how would we do that _discussion_ without OP commenting on their question? Again: I've got some doubts that this question is worthy an answer to add valuable input for a FAQ like format.

Comment: I gave significant hints. So I am sure this answer is useful. But I don't want to do the homework of OP

Comment: Sure, no doubts about your answer is useful. But the question is not really awesome, let's start with the title.

Comment: for clarification: I am not asking you to do my homework, in fact, I have a lot of it done, but why would I crowd my question with unnecessary code? I was confused on a small part that played a role in my program which is why I asked this question. Also, I made sure to not word my question in a way where it made it sound like I wanted someone to do my HW for me by explaining what my understanding was, and if my understanding is wrong then hopefully someone would point that out to me. Please don't take this question the wrong way.

Comment: Because you need to provide an [MCVE] which should be *minimal* (so cannot be a raw copy of all your code). You are required to *extract* from your current code some *minimal* example. Asking a question often require half an hour of work.

Comment: @daisygal Well, your question sounds like homework, because all of these silly restrictions coming out from nowhere. No real programmer would even give it a thought about, without having really strong reasonings.

Comment: Also, thank you @Basile Starynkevitch, your answer definitely guided me in the right direction!